# tmux fails with 'server exited unexpectedly ' upon send-keys

Tags: tmux

I am fresh new to tmux.  After going through Hogan's tutorial, I created a tmux script file for my environment.  when I run this script, it fails on the send-key function.  My script is as below.

```
set -x
# Creates a session with a name 'todos'
tmux new-session -s todos -n backend -d

# cd to the project directory and open vim editor
tmux send-keys -t todos 'cd ~/projects/explore/mongo-app/' C-m
tmux send-keys -t todos 'nvim' C-m

set +x
```

When I debug the script, it shows that it failed at send-keys function, as below.

```
++ tmux new-session -s todos -n backend -d
++ tmux send-keys -t todos 'cd ~/projects/explore/mongo-app/' C-m
server exited unexpectedly
++ tmux send-keys -t todos nvim C-m
```

I am using tmux 3.0a on Ubuntu 20.04.  How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a bug, please try tmux 3.1 and if the problem still exists, please open an issue at https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues.

Answer (score 1):

@Nicholas 
After some struggling, I understood that when I created a new tmux-session, it was not in a command-ready state to accept shell commands.  When I launch tmux without -d (detached) option, it was showing an error like below:

[image]

This was due to an invalid command in tmux.conf.

So, for any next command, it was crashing.  When I removed the offending line from tmux.conf, everything works fine.

Comment: Ah yes - this was a bug, I had forgotten - it should not crash when you do it, it just shouldn't work. I think it is fixed already in 3.1. But you would need to remove the line in any case.